# Mongoose models typing fails

Tags: typescript, mongodb, express, mongoose, schema

i'm working with products and categories 
i need that product model's categories type to be an array of Category

##### i've created these two types

```js
type Category = {
    parent: Category | null;  // is this ok?
    name: String;
};
type Product = {
    categories: Category[];
    name: String;
    qty: Number;
    price: Number;
};
```

##### then i've created the models

```js
// category model
import { Schema, Types, model } from "mongoose";
import Category from "../types/Category";

const categorySchema = new Schema(
    {
        parent: { type: Category | null, required: true },      // NEED HELP WITH THIS TYPE
        name: { type: String, required: true },
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);

export default model("Category", categorySchema);
```

```js
// product model
import { Schema, Types, model } from "mongoose";
import Category from "../types/Category";

const productSchema = new Schema(
    {
        categories: { type: [Category], required: true },     // NEED HELP WITH THIS TYPE
        name: { type: String, required: true }
        qty: { type: Number, required: true }
        price: { type: Number, required: true }
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);

export default model("Product", productSchema);
```

##### vs code shows no error but when i run the server that's the error i get:

isn't productSchema's categories type an array of Category?

i've also tried `categories: { type: Types.Array<Category>, required: true }` with no success

##### if i pass the categorySchema like this

```js
// product model
import { Schema, Types, model } from "mongoose";
import categorySchema from "./category.model";

const productSchema = new Schema(     // should i pass something here? like Schema<xxxxxxx>
    {
        categories: { type: [categorySchema], required: true },     // categorySchema instead of Category type
        name: { type: String, required: true }
        qty: { type: Number, required: true }
        price: { type: Number, required: true }
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);

export default model("Product", productSchema);
```

it fails as well

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference the `Category` model in both cases:

```
const categorySchema = new Schema(
  {
    parent: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category' },
    name: { type: String, required: true },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const productSchema = new Schema(
  {
      categories: [{ 
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'Category',
        default: []
      }],
      name: { type: String, required: true }
      qty: { type: Number, required: true }
      price: { type: Number, required: true }
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

You will need to `populate` the categories on retrieval:

```
Category.find().populate('parent').exec();
Product.find().populate('categories').exec();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give a reference to the category model in the product schema. Use this it will help you.

```
categories: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Category", required: true }],
```

Comment: do i have to import Category model to Product model file or mongoose handles it automatically?

Comment: what about "parent" of Category model? i want it to be Category or null. how do i make a ref to self?

Comment: Yes, you can set self-ref of your model. you just need to pass the collection name in ref which you have set in model exports. mongoose will automatically handle it when you want to get that ref data. you just have to use populate and you will get that documents